# Summation of max function with vector input in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I want to build this function: f(a,b)=sum_{i=1 to n}(max(a-b_i,0)) where b=(b_1,b_2,...b_n).  This is what I have done:

```
    vec<-function(a,b){
                  z<-0
                   for(i in b){
                         ifelse(a > i,z <- z + (a-i), 0)
                       }
                return(data.frame(z))
                   }
```

This code gives correct output for scalar input of a. But while using vector output answers are not always correct. For example

```
    > vec(c(-6,5),c(3,1,3)) 
  gives -25 for a=-6 and 8 for a=5 respectively. 

 But   > vec(-6,c(3,1,3))  gives 0. And this the correct answer.
```

Please throw give some idea how will I correct it.

Comment: You might want to use `?pmax`.

Comment: Then can u tell me how do I rewrite it.

Comment: @imo Thank you so much. Now the code runs well.

Answer (score 0):

When you let `a = c(-6,5)`, then this argument `a > i` becomes `(FALSE, TRUE)`. Since it contains a true, the vector is passed into `z <- z + (a-i)`. Note that if you use `a=-6` in this formula, you get the output of `-25`. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
vec<-function(a,b){
z<-0
for(i in b){
p <- ifelse(a > i,z <- z + (a-i), 0)
}
return(data.frame(p))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are missing is the condition on only summing up positive numbers, as expressed by the condition 'max(a-b_i, 0)'.

This code works fine for the examples you provide:

```
vec <- function(a, b){
  n <- NULL
  for(i in 1:length(a)){
    z <- a[i] - b
    z <- z[z > 0]
    n <- c(n, sum(z))
  }
  
  return(n)
}
```

For example:

```
> vec(c(-6, 5), c(3, 1, 3))
[1] 0 8
```

and

```
> vec(-6, c(3, 1, 3))
[1] 0
```

If you want to get a data.frame back just replace the `return(n)` instruction to `return(data.frame(n))`.